# Why Cic testnet transaction cost is high?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, testnets, blockchain-size

I was testing my smart contract on cic testnet but the transaction cost for a simple transaction like updating the string was asked for 65 cict how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was with the EVM version to deploy your smart contract on the CICT test net with the noraml transaction's cost we need to change the EVM version.
update it to ***Petersburg***